# creating Event Viewer Applications and Services Logs

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

On my server I want to create custom logs for different applications.  How is this done as a  server administration exercise?

Comment: Unless you're writing the applications yourself, the applications won't know to write to the new logs that you've created.

Comment: yes, these are our own custom applications!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use PowerShell's New-EventLog cmdlet to do this.  More info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315363.aspx).

mfinni is right though.  This is only useful for your own applications or scripts and such as you won't be able to redirect other apps to your new event log.

Comment: Exactly - this ain't syslog.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran the New-EventLog powershell cmdlet and seemingly added the log (no errors). However, I am not seeing the new log listed under the Applications and Services Logs node in the Event Viewer. Is there another step?

Comment: From the article I cited - "This cmdlet creates a new classic event log on a local or remote computer."  So the log will be under Windows Logs not Applications and Services.