# using New-EventLog to create logs under Applications and Services Logs

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I am trying to get the new log to appear as a node under the Applications and Services Logs node in the event viewer, and I just learned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/317296/creating-event-viewer-applications-and-services-logs/317341#317341) that the Powershell cmdlet New-EventLog will create a new event log.

I ran the cmdlet and it ran with no errors, so seemingly it worked.  However, I am not seeing the new event log even after a right-click/refresh of the Applications and Services Logs folder.

Is there another step to make this appear?

My goal is for our custom applications to be able to write to application specific event logs located under Applications and Services Logs for easier monitoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer lies [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315363.aspx), in the notes near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It made me reread those notes, and although I had already made 'note' of those, it tweaked a thought that maybe shutting down the Event Viewer and reopening would make them appear. I did that and voila, the logs appeared. The notes say that no logs are created until actually written to, but that is not the behavior I am seeing. If I create the log, shut down Event Viewer and reopen, I can see it.

Comment: Glad to help...